# Pause a running Batch script and then restart after second key stroke

Tags: batch-file, pause

I have a batch file that will run a macro.  The macro will automatically run all day but I want to be able to start and stop it with a simple keyboard character.  Is there a way in the code that I can add a "Press S to stop, and R to Resume"? The resume would start my vbs file again.

```
powershell -window minimized -command ""
@echo off

pause
 cls
:start 
cscript DisplayBoard2.vbs "S:\filepath\macro.xlsm"
goto start
```

Comment: You could use the search facility at the top of the page, or your chosen search engine to research theses things! Remove your last line, then use `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C RS /N /M "Press S to stop, and R to Resume"` followed by `If Not ErrorLevel 2 GoTo start`. Please note however, you'd need to `[ENTER]` `R`, or `S` after each instance of your cscript.exe command, (macro enabled Excel file), is closed, and to do that, you'd have to restrore the minimized `cmd.exe` window, in order to bring it into focus for the key entry.

Comment: Alternatively add the following two lines after the `:start` line: `%SystemRoot%\System32\choice.exe /C RS /N /M "Press S to stop, and R to Resume"`, and `If ErrorLevel 2 Exit /B`, In both cases, I'd assume you could optionally remove the `pause` line.

Comment: Thanks @Compo but that doesn't do what I was looking for.  I want the batch file to run automatically and then if someone wants to stop it, they press S and then R when they want to restart it.  Should I just make three different batch codes and then run each one?

Comment: You cannot press a key inside a window which is minimized, (to the taskbar). Apart from that, if you don't want to `Exit`, you can `Pause` or `timeout` instead, _(the method/technique is no different)_!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `choice` command to do what you want.

Note: the script window has to be active for it to work. `Cmd` has no possibility to "intercept" keypresses if the window is not active.

```
@echo OFF
:start
echo running. Press 'S' to suspend.
REM your payload here
choice /c SX /n /t 1 /d X >nul
if errorlevel 2 goto :start
:pause
echo paused. Press 'R' to resume.
choice /c RX /n /t 1 /d X >nul
if errorlevel 2 goto :pause
goto :start
```

What (I guess) you really want, is called a keylogger (to catch keyboard input regardless of what application has the focus). See [this site](https://www.codeguru.com/visual-basic/creating-a-simple-keylogger-in-visual-basic/) for how it basically works.

Comment: thanks for your reply.  When i put in my batch file name after start it doesnt work to show the different codes.  Where should I put the name of my batch file in order for it to start running.

Comment: According to your question, your payload is `cscript DisplayBoard2.vbs "S:\filepath\macro.xlsm"`. (Minimizing is counterproductive because the window has to be active to recognize the keystrokes). If your payload is another batch file, you need to `call` it.

Comment: Thanks @Stephan however it still wont launch my script.  It just keeps repeating "running. Press S to Suspend".

Comment: correct - until you press 'S'. (hint: you can remove both `echo` lines after troubleshooting)

Comment: thanks the program will launch but I cannot type S in the CMD screen.  Is there a specific function I need to press to allow me to type an S?

Comment: The `cmd` window has to have the focus to work (as explained in my answer)

Comment: @Stephen, I understand it has to have the focus but I am new to this and I am unsure how to make it the focus.

Comment: The active window (the window with the focus) is the window which you are interacting with and is accepting input. Just click on a window/application to make it active.